# How to redirect from NgOnInit?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I want to redirect, under certain conditions, when the page is loaded or before. For example, Cookies have to have something, then do a redirect.

`this.router.navigate(["details"]);` in AppComponent.NgOnInit not working!

Routers:

```
const APP_ROUTES : Route[] = [
  { path: '', component: FormComponent, children: FORM_ROUTES},
  { path: 'details', component: DetailsComponent}
];
```

Module imports and bootstrap:

```
imports: [
BrowserModule,
FormsModule,
HttpModule,
RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES),
RouterModule.forChild(FORM_ROUTES)
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

Angular 2.

Comment: You should use Router Guards to do conditional redirects.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? How do your routes look like. What component contains above code?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer updated

Comment: Have you tried `this.router.navigate(["/details"]);` (with `/`)?

Comment: However in function AppComponent.ClickToRedirect() this is working.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes

Comment: You're missing the / in the example above. As  Günter mentioned it should be /details because you're navigating from the index.html

Comment: @Bhetzie It does not help

Comment: Did you change the path to path:{ path: /'details', component: DetailsComponent} ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CanActivate](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html) decided my problem

In **Router**

```
{ path: '', component: FormComponent, children: FORM_ROUTES},
{ path: 'details', component: DetailsComponent, canActivate [NoAuthRedirectService]}
```

In **NoAuthRedirectService**

```
canActivate() : boolean
  {
    if(!this.auth.OnAuth())
    {
      this.router.navigate(["/"]);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```